# Jquery Validate Plugin Keydown

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the Jquery Validate plugin, is there a way of validating as soon as the first key is pressed and showing the error messages until they have entered what is required?

So the first keypress in an input field I want the validation message to appear, until they have correctly inputted what is required

My code is below

```
       <?php
// Error Config
include_once("PHP/Config.php");
// Session
include_once("PHP/Session.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>TBA </title>

<meta name="description" content="Coming soon
<meta name="keywords" content="

" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>

<link href="CSS/Site_Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/Register_Form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="JS/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#SignUp").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                password: true,
                notEqual: "#password"
            },
            company: {
                nls: true,
                required: true
            },
            telephone: {
                phone: true
            }
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("email", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid email address");

    $.validator.addMethod("password", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,16}$/i.test(value);
    }, "Passwords are 6-16 characters");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == param;
    }, "Passwords Do Not Match");

    $.validator.addMethod("nls", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\-_']+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please Only Enter Alpha Numeric Characters");

    $.validator.addMethod("phone", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /(\s*\(?0\d{4}\)?\s*\d{6}\s*)|(\s*\(?0\d{3}\)?\s*\d{3}\s*\d{4}\s*)/i.test(value);
    }, "Please Only Enter UK Telephone Numbers");

});
</script>




</head>

<body>
<div id="Site_Holder">

<div id="Header_Holder">
<?php include_once "PHP/Inserts/Header_Content.php";?>
</div><!-- Header Holder End -->

<div id="Navigation_Holder">

<?php include_once "PHP/Inserts/Navigation_Content.php";?>


</div><!-- Navigation Holder End -->

<div id="Content_Holder">

    <div id="Register_Form_Holder" class="General_text">

         <div class="Blank_Divider">Register a Climbing Centre<br/>
        <br/></div>

        <div class="Blank_Divider"></div>
        <form id="SignUp">



        <div class="Name_Form_Field">E-mail Address:</div>
        <div class="Input_Form_Field"><input id="email" name="email"/></div>

        <div class="Blank_Divider"></div>

        <div class="Name_Form_Field">Password:</div> 
        <div class="Input_Form_Field"><input id="password" name="password" type="password" /></div>

        <div class="Blank_Divider"></div>

        <div class="Name_Form_Field">Confirm Password:</div> 
        <div class="Input_Form_Field"><input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" /></div>

        <div class="Blank_Divider"></div>


        <div class="Blank_Divider">Header
        <br/>
        <br/></div>

        <div class="Name_Form_Field"> Name:</div> 
        <div class="Input_Form_Field"><input id="company" name="company" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="Blank_Divider"></div>

        <div class="Name_Form_Field">Contact Telephone Number:</div> 
        <div class="Input_Form_Field"><input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text" /></div>



        </form>



    </div>


</div><!-- Content Holder End -->

<div id="Footer_Holder">

<?php include_once "PHP/Inserts/Footer_Content.php";?>

</div><!-- Footer Holder End -->


</div><!-- Site Holder End -->
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You're asking for the default behavior of the plugin.  Show your code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: You forgot to include the HTML markup of the form in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Using the Jquery Validate plugin, is there a way of validating as soon as the first key is pressed and showing the error messages until they have entered what is required?  So the first keypress in an input field I want the validation message to appear, until they have correctly inputted what is required."*

That is already the default behavior of the plugin.  (The `onkeyup` option is enabled by default.)

See this simple demo, where as soon as you enter one character into the first field (with the `email` rule), the message immediately tells you to enter a valid email address.  As soon as you enter one character into the second field, the `minlength` rule tells you to enter at least 10 characters.  And if you start filling out a field and then delete it, the message for the `required` rule will appear.  Messages will appear in the order that their rules are declared (with the exception of the `required` rule).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            field3: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyR9C/**

---

**EDIT**:

Same jsFiddle but with code as posted in OP's edit:

Still working: http://jsfiddle.net/yyR9C/1/

Comment: I can see from jsfiddle that your solution works and thats how I want it to validate, but for some reason mine still only validates once you tab out of the field, my code is below

Comment: @user2224798, I simply dropped your code into my jsFiddle and it's working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyR9C/1/  ~  You're going to have to carefully examine your code as compared to the working code in the jsFiddle.

Comment: @user2224798, Also, you don't need to create rules called `nls`, `phone`, and `notequal`... these rules already exist as part of the plugin, however, with `alphanumeric` and `phoneUK`, you'll need to include the `additional-methods.js` file.  And when you want to match the password field, using `required` and `password` rules twice is redundant since the `equalTo` rule ensures that the second field ***must*** match the first.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyR9C/2/

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have gone through my page and I can't see anything wrong, I have pasted all my code above now, if you get any time to have a look at it, I would be grateful, I am sure your really busy.

Comment: @user2224798,  the HTML code you posted is basically the same as in my jsFiddle demos.  You can see they're working fine, so you just have to be extra vigilant about comparing the jsFiddle code to yours.  Are you using the latest versions of the plugins? Are you seeing any console errors, etc?  Otherwise, I've correctly answered your question and there's nothing else I can do with what you've shown.

Comment: Cheers Sparky for your help

Comment: Yes, Sparky helped lot. Even he did help in my question too. I was using jquery validate v.14. It wasn't working when I get down to version 10. Now it's working fine. Thanks Sparky.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your validate code with this

```js
    $("#SignUp").validate({
     onkeyup: function(element) {
      $(element).valid(); 
    },    
    rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                password: true
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                password: true,
                notEqual: "#password"
            },
            company: {
                nls: true,
                required: true
            },
            telephone: {
                phone: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand the question very well, but I think you can user the `keyup` event from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Something like that

```
$("#formId input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
     $("#formId").valid(); 
     // Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.
```

see [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).

});

or something like that. Please give more details.Have a good day.

Comment: No, no, no... if you understood that `.validate()` is the initialization method of the plugin, then you'd realize your solution cannot work.